# Solve $2y''+y'=0$ using power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I got the answer $C_0e^{-x/2}$ by doing 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(x^{n-1}\right) \left(2n\left(n+1\right)C_{n+1}\:\right)+\left(nC_n\right) = 0$$
thus giving 
$$C_{n+1}= -\dfrac{C_n}{2(n+1)}.$$
This leads me to the answer $y = C_0e^{-x/2}$.

However, the answer in my textbook is $C_1e^{-x/2} + C_0$.  I've found this to be true, but still couldn't figure out a method of solving the equation so that there are two constants.

Edit: what my textbook did was  $$c_{n+2}= -\dfrac{1}{2(n+2)}c_{n+1}.$$  , and then  substitute $$c_{0}=C_0-2c_1$$  and $$c_1=\dfrac{-1}{2}C_1$$    into $y=c_0 +c_1 - \dfrac{1}{2*2!}c_{1} x^2. + \dfrac{1}{2^2*3!}c_{1} x^3........$

Where did the substitutions come from?

Comment: If you substitute $y(x) = C_0 + C_1 x + C_2 x^2 + \ldots$  then the equation reads $2(2C_2 + 3C_3 x + \ldots) + (C_1 + 2C_2 x + \ldots) = 0$. The recurssion you get only holds from $n=1$ so $C_0$ can be anything so and $C_n$ is determined by $C_1$ giving you a solution on the form $Ae^{-x/2} + B$.

Comment: You can fix the underdetermination with regularization.

Comment: Also don't omit the question in the text-body even if you have it in title.

Comment: Use Picard's rule.

Comment: The problem is that you translated each identity $$2n\left(n+1\right)C_{n+1}+nC_n = 0$$ as $$2\left(n+1\right)C_{n+1}+C_n = 0$$ This holds true for every $n\ne0$ but not for $n=0$.

Comment: @Cesareo No thanks.

Comment: @Did With Picard's rule we solve $2u'+u = c_0$ with $u = y'$

Comment: @Cesareo And this is not needed at all (besides, what you call "Picard's rule" is unclear).

Comment: @Did By Picard's rule I mean the iterative solution construction. Is quite simple.

Comment: @Cesareo I was afraid this was what you were alluding to. Then indeed your hint is squarely misleading.

Comment: There's another constant because the equation is cast in terms of y' & y" rather than y & y'. You get the former from the latter just by differentiating the whole equation. When you compare powers  to get your recursion for the coefficients, that recursion depends only on the _difference_ in order of derivative. If you add a constant to each function, when you do that differentiation of the entire equation, and increase the order of each term by 1, the constant vanishes. ¶ The number of constants is _always_ equal to the maximum order - it's a fundamental property of differential equations.

Answer (score -1):

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d^2}y }{\mathrm{d} x^2}=-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} \\
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d}x}\left ( \frac{\mathrm{d}y }{\mathrm{d} x} \right ) = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} \\
\ln{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}} = \frac{-x}{2}+c \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = c_{1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}
\\ y=c_{1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}+c_{2}
$$

Comment: The intent is to use power series.